# Can I instruct Kotlin to associateBy the first element instead of the last element matching the key extractor?

Tags: kotlin, merge, sequence

Consider this fine example:

```
listOf(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(2, "b"), Pair(1, "b")).associateBy { it.first }
```

The output associates the last value with each key:

```
> (1 to "b", 2 to "b")
```

Is there a way to get the opposite behaviour? i.e. associate the first values with a key?

```
> (1 to "a", 2 to "b")
```

I understand I can sort the list, use groupingBy + reduce, etc, but assume the list is huge and performance becomes an issue. So I'd like to know if there is any way I can tell Kotlin how I intend my records to be merged

Similar to Java's Collectors method:

```
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

Where I can specify the merge function:

```
Collectors.toMap(Pair::value1(), Pair::value2(), (first, second) -> first)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse it beforehand (the first items will override the latest because they are the latest now):

```
listOf(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(2, "b"), Pair(1, "b")).asReversed().toMap() // {1=a, 2=b}
```

Overhead is insignificant, the `asReversed` method doesn't create a reversed copy of the original list, it just creates a simple wrapper with overridden `get` method, delegating all calls to the original list.

Comment: Extra points for describing the implementation of the reversed function

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `associateBy` does, here's what your code returns:

```
{1=(1, b), 2=(2, b)}
```

It's taking each item in the list, and storing that whole thing as a *value* in a map, using the key generated by the function you provide.

(If you want the output you provided, `(1 to "b", 2 to "b")`, you just call `toMap` on the list - a `Pair` is a way to provide a key/value entry for a map)

---

The reason you're getting two values with `"b"` as their 2nd element is because you have two items with the same 1st element, so they both generate the same key, and the last one (with the `"b"`) ends up overwriting the first in the map.

It's not clear exactly what you want with your example, but if you're saying you want to collect *the first entry that uses each key* (so `(1, "b")` doesn't overwrite `(1, "a")` then you can use `distinctBy`:

```
val wow = listOf(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(2, "b"), Pair(1, "b")).distinctBy { it.first }.toMap()
println(wow)
>>> {1=a, 2=b}
```

or you could use `it.second` if you want only the first appearance of each value for the 2nd element (which coincidentally gives you the same result - this is why the example isn't clear!)

If you want more specific control over the mapping, you probably want `associate`:

- [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html) (which you used) iterates over each item, and the function you provide generates the *key* - the *value* is the item
- [`associateWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-with.html) is the opposite - the item is the key, your function generates the value.
- [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) takes an item, and your function produces the key **and** value, so you have more control over what the resulting map looks like

If you have a more specific example of what you need to do, someone might be able to provide a better fit, but those are probably the functions you want to look at.

If you're worried about memory/performance with large data sets, you might want to call `toSequence()` on the list so you're not generating intermediate collections (but that depends on what those intermediate operations are exactly - `distinctBy` is probably going to need to build an intermediate collection so it knows what to drop) . Or look at the `to` versions of the associate stuff (e.g. [`associateByTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by-to.html)) where you provide a mutable map to add stuff into. Depends what you're doing and whether the gains are worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Although its not very clear what are you trying to accomplish here, but the java code that you have specified have no direct mapping solution in kotlin. However its very easy to write a wrapper around `grouping` and `aggregate` to get the desired result

```
/**
 * Generates a map where keys are given by keyMapper and values are given by valueMapper.
 * If any two elements would have the same key returned by [keyMapper]
 * then merge function is used to merge the values of such keys.
 * T: type of Iterable elements
 * K: type of keys
 * R: type of values
 *
 * @return Map<K,R>
 */
private inline fun <T, K, R> Iterable<T>.toMapWithMerge(
        crossinline keyMapper: (T) -> K,
        valueMapper: (T) -> R,
        merge: (R, R) -> R
): Map<K, R>{
    return groupingBy(keyMapper).aggregate { key, accumulator:R?, element, first ->
        if(accumulator == null) valueMapper(element)
        else merge(accumulator, valueMapper(element))
    }
}
```

and you can use it as

```
listOf(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(2, "b"), Pair(1, "b"))
                .toMapWithMerge({ it.first }, { it.second }, { first, second -> first })
```

and as for the performance part, this is not going to perform any worse then the java counterpart, since it performs only a single iteration which will cost you no more than `O(n)`